# How to change value of one textbox instantly as soon as the value of another textbox is going to change

Tags: asp.net

I am making an asp.net webpage where i am having three textbox.
Let's consider textbox1, textbox2, textbox3. Now when i load the page The default value which textbox1 is having is 10000. Now i want to enter a value into textbox2. As soon as i enter value into textbox2 it should automatically show the remaining value in textbox3.
Example:
Default value of Textbox1 value is 10000.
When i enter 1500 into textbox2.
value of textbox3 should be 8500. It should change instantly as soon as the value of textbox2 is going to change. Whatever may be the value of textbox2, it should get subtract from textbox1 and should get flashed on textbox3 instantly without pressing any button.

Comment: You will need javascript to do this. Have you used javascript of jquery before?

Comment: please show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, the easiest by far is KnockoutJS

You can bind a model to all three textboxes. The third box will have a `computed observable` bound to it.

like so:

Assuming your UI code looks like this:

```
<div id="application">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: init1, valueUpdate='afterkeydown'" value="1000"/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: init2, valueUpdate='afterkeydown'"/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: computed"/>
</div>
```

The JavaScript code will look like so:

```
$(function(){
    var ViewModel = new function(){
        this.init1 = ko.observable(1000);
        this.init2 = ko.observable(0);
        this.computed = ko.computed(function(){ 
            return this.init1() - this.init2();
        });
    };

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('application');
});
```

You'll need jQuery and KnockoutJS for this to work.

Comment: it is like textbox1 is getting value from a database. User can only enter value to textbox2 and textbox3 is going to show the subtracted value automatically

Comment: @AbhishekPradhan this is client side code. This magic is only possible on the client side. However, you can write Ajax calls to pull data to and from the ViewModel(vm)